# Conditional Probability Dealing with Four Events

Tags: probability

My professor mentioned that before each class, he had tea, coffee, or water. The events were set up as follows:

$P(C)=.6, P(T) = .3, P(W) = .1$
=> Where C, T, and W are the probabilities of drinking Coffee, Tea or Water respectively. Now, my professor mentioned **he may or may not end lecture** **early** depending on which one he drank.

*Let $l=$ event that lecture is ended early*

The following probabilities are then as follows:

$P(L|C) = .2, P(L|T) = .1, P(L|W) = 0$

From this, I've managed to construct a conditional probability tree. I've also managed to figure out what $P(L \cap C) = .12$ by doing the following:

$$P(L|C)=\frac{P(L\cap C)}{P(C)}=>\frac{P(L \cap C)}{.6} =.2$$

My question now comes down to, how can I individually calculate $P(L)$ along with $P(C | L)$. I actually have no idea on how to start on these. I tried a summation of all the probabilities where L occurs, which just gives .3, but I don't feel that is correct. So to summarize my question, **how can I calculate**  $P(L)$ and $P(C|L)$?

Using the rules for **Total Probability**, I've believe (without confirmation) that the following should work?

$$P(L) = P(L|C)P(C)+P(L|T)P(T)+P(L|W)P(W) => (.2)(.6)+(.1)(.3)+0=>.15$$

Comment: Hint: Try to find the words "Bayes formula" in your notes.

Comment: You can also use the "law of total probability," which allows you to compute the probability of a complicated thing by conditioning on simpler things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(L)\ne0.3$ as you suspect. The correct value may be obtained by first working out $P(L\cap T)=0.03$ and $P(L\cap W)=0$ in the same way as $P(L\cap C)$was derived. Then $P(L)$ is the sum of these three probabilities, since $C,T,W$ are mutually exclusive and no other drink is taken:
$$P(L)=0.12+0.03+0=0.15$$
So your working is correct. $P(C\mid L)$ is one division away:
$$P(C\mid L)=\frac{P(C\cap L)}{P(L)}=\frac{0.12}{0.15}=0.8$$